# How to Automatically Open Text File: Find, Copy Data, and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to automate a task that involves opening a whole folder of .ist documents that are similar and paste the data. I already have code that allows me to click each item but I'm trying to make this task **completely automatic.** I'm pretty new at this. I have experience coding in C but I've been coding vba for only a week.

So here's what I have:

This is the code that works

```
Sub Figureitout()

    Dim fileName As Variant, text(1 To 890) As String, textline As String
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim strDir As String, fso As Object, objFiles As Object, obj As Object, fileCount As Integer
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim posTorque As Integer, posOffset As Integer

        'specify folder path
        strDir = "C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\"

        'create filesystemobj
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        'get the folder
        Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(strDir).Files

        'count all the files
        fileCount = objFiles.Count

        'Total number of files in folder
        MsgBox fileCount

        'read file name
        'fileName = Dir(strDir)
        'MsgBox fileName

        'counter intitialize
        num = 1

        Do Until num = fileCount

            'choose file
            myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files(*.IST),*.ist", , , , False)

                'open file
                Open myFile For Input As #num

                    'copy file contents
                    Do Until EOF(num)
                        Line Input #(num), textline
                        text(num) = text(num) & textline

                    Loop

                    'find data
                    posTorque = InStr(text(num), "Torque:")
                    posOffset = InStr(text(num), "Offset:")

                    'close file
                    Close #num

                'make sure offset value exists in document
                If InStr(text(num), "Offset:") <> 0 Then

                    'paste data
                    Range("A" & num).Value = Mid(text(num), posTorque + 12, 4)
                    Range("B" & num).Value = Mid(text(num), posOffset + 13, 4)

                End If

                'delete chosen file
                Kill (myFile)

            'increment prior to loop
            num = num + 1

            'Reset data
            posTorque = 0
            posOffset = 0

        Loop

End Sub
```

So I'm thinking about having something that is like:

```
For Each fileName in fileCount
   FileName = "Dir(strDir)"
   Open fileName for Input As #num
```

but I keep getting type mismatch errors. I'm assuming that's because fileName is a string in this scenario?

Tips? Tricks? Advice?

Comment: I would look at other questions here on SO on how to use `Dir`...

Comment: I would follow @BigBen suggestion. Also, you already have all the files in the folder (in `objFiles`). I don't think you need this: `myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files(*.IST),*.ist", , , , False)`. You could just loop through all the files using `objFiles`. For `DIR`, remove quotes: `FileName = Dir(strDir)`

Answer (score 1):

No need to store the complete text from all the files in an array, just check each lines as you read it.

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sFilename As String, textline As String
    Dim i As Integer, ff As Integer, p As Integer, count As Long

    sFilename = Dir(FOLDER & "*.ist") ' first file

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    i = 0
    Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
        ff = FreeFile
        i = i + 1

        Open FOLDER & sFilename For Input As #ff

        Do Until EOF(ff)
            Line Input #ff, textline

            p = InStr(textline, "Torque:")
            If p > 0 Then
                ws.Range("A" & i).Value = Mid(textline, p + 12, 4)
            End If

            p = InStr(textline, "Offset:")
            If p > 0 Then
                Range("B" & i).Value = Mid(textline, p + 13, 4)
            End If
        Loop
        Close ff

        sFilename = Dir ' get next
        count = count + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox count & " files proccessed in " & FOLDER, vbInformation

End Sub
```